# How to authorise an application to use Facebook credentials of Setting in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, facebook

In my app I want to add Facebook Login. I have already done that but the problem as of now is I get a Pop Up to login via Facebook. I want if user has installed Facebook application in his device there should not come any pop up for login. As the user has already provided his credentials to the device.  The basic intention is to use the credentials of setting and log in to the my app without so that Facebook installed app user doest need to give his/her credentials again.

Comment: check [facebook developer-> iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) link. it has all the answers.

Comment: I checked the docs but I am unable to get the access token from setting ..kindly guide

Comment: check the Adding the login UI control -> FBLoginView. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1). do it by your self, if you find any issue , then post here.

Comment: i have done accordingly . But whenever i tried to login it navigates to Facebook app screen for sometime returns back. I don't want that. my app should silently login without going to Facebook app for a single time even. help

Comment: at first user must give permission to your app.it will not ask for permission every time. once user will give you permission , at second login attempt it will show that , user has already authorized the permission. check it for your self. [facebook permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#permissions)

Comment: @DipeshPokhrel how did you solve it?